# Arithmetic overflow when setting relative time for SetWaitableTimer

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I want the timer to start signalling 5 minutes and 5 seconds from the current time, but when I set the QuadPart of LARGE_INTEGER to -3050000000, the variable overflows and when I print it out, it appears as 1244967296. What should I do to make it signal 5 minutes 5 seconds(or more) from the current time?

```
LARGE_INTEGER li;
li.QuadPart = -3050000000;
printf( "%ld\n", li );
```

Answer (score 5):

Following the example linked to from your link:

```
LARGE_INTEGER li;
li.QuadPart = -3050000000LL;
```

The "LL" makes it a long long literal; without it it's just an `int`.
(You *can* use lowercase "l", but they are very similar to "1" (one) in many fonts.)

Comment: What if -3050000000LL is stored in a variable?

Comment: @shawn: I don't understand your question. Do you mean something like `long long time = -3050000000LL; li.QuadPart = time`? If so, what's the problem? As long as it's a long long, it will just work.

Answer (score 4):

```
LARGE_INTEGER alarm_after;  
alarm_after.QuadPart =  -1 * (seconds * 10000000LL);
printf("Quadpart=%I64x\n", alarm_after.Quadpart);
```